# "vest" as a phrasal verb

Tags: verbs, legalese

Rather than memorising [the definitions](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vest_2), how could I intuit and rationalise them:

1. **vest in somebody/something = to belong to somebody/something legally**.
2. **vest something in somebody** =  to give somebody the legal right or power to do something

For example, in 2, the order of **something** and **somebody** is reversed; **something** precedes **somebody** in the phrase but vice versa in the definition? An example of 1:

> The Independent Counsel Law—which **vests** the selection **in** a panel of judges—having lapsed
>   when the Lewinsky matter surfaced, Attorney General Janet Reno at first decided that she would have
>   to appoint a special prosecutor to investigate President Clinton.

Source: P294, America on Trial, Alan Dershowitz

Comment: How is this a phrasal verb?

Comment: @tchrist Please explain; I merely copied it from the link.

Comment: The phrasal verb is _vest in_ and as you have correctly highlighted it can be split to _vest something in_.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the interpretation of legalese, not English.

Comment: @tchrist When did the phrasal verb 'vest in' drop out of English, I'm not good at spotting these things any more, but I guess the OED have a whole heap of obsoleting to do.

Comment: Pay attention to the prepositions. Definition (1): *"the selection vests **in** a panel of judges";* this usage seems old-fashioned to me, although I can still find a few instances of it with Google. Don't bother learning it. Definition (2): *"The award committee vests the selection **in** a panel of judges"* or *"the award committee vests a panel of judges **with** the selection"* or *"the selection **is vested in** a panel of judges"* or *"a panel of judges **is vested with** the selection".* This usage is much more common nowadays.

Comment: And your example, which you are calling an example of (1), is really an example of (2).

Comment: I _really_ don’t understand what you’re trying to ask here at all. The two meanings are basically the same, only with a transitive/intransitive difference. As @PeterShor says, the intransitive use is archaic—don’t bother too much with it. The transitive use is common enough. What do you mean “the order of _something_ and _somebody_ is reversed”? _Something_ is the direct object of _vest_. _Somebody_ is the object of the preposition _in_; the prepositional phrase as a whole is an argument of the verb. What order the two come in is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the approach taken by *Black's Law Dictionary* would make more sense to you than Oxford's treatment (which you link to). Black's simply focuses on the meaning of *vested* without worrying about what slightly different senses the verb *vest* may take under different (but closely allied) circumstances. Most of Black's detailed discussion of the different legal senses that *vested* may have comes in entries for specific types of vesting (*vested estate*, *vested gift*, *vested interest*, and *vested rights*, for example). From *Black's Law Dictionary*, fourth revised edition (1968):

> **VESTED.** Fixed; accrued; settled; absolute. [Citations omitted.] Having the character or giving the rights of absolute ownership; not contingent; not subject to be defeated by a condition precedent.

Working backward from this definition to your original quotation from Alan Dershowitz's book, we may conclude that the phrase "the Independent Counsel Law vests the selection in a panel of judges" means "the Independent Counsel Law settles or fixes or irrevocably assigns responsibility for the selection on [or to] a panel of judges."